# Why didn't the family go live near the waterfall?

Tags: a-quiet-place

In the first movie the dad takes his son near a waterfall where they can even shout or scream but the aliens wouldn't hear it because of the ambient sound.

So why didn't the family go live near the waterfall? Or near another loud ambient sound? Or at least go have the baby in the waterfall where the mom can scream at will?

Is it addressed at all in the book?

Comment: What book? It was based on an original screenplay

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89726/why-doesnt-the-family-live-next-to-the-waterfall

Comment: One might suggest it is because people who live near waterfalls don't realize when they are yelling and stomping around.  A terrible trait to have cultivated in a world where you have to constantly search for supplies while being dead quiet.  Also, maybe they just weren't skilled at carpentry.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really addressed in the book, but I can offer some reasons why this isn't a good idea:

- Too loud for children: the loud noise of the waterfall is way too loud for the children to live normally
- Too tricky too build a new structure from scratch: You are gonna have to make a new structure with minimal tools, even if you found the resources, transporting and building is going to take forever
- It's alright to have some loud ambient sounds, but keeping that "playing" for long periods of time can really affect your mental health.